# Turn off mailgun in development enviroment

Tags: meteor

I'm constantly tinkering with my app and pushing updates live. Unfortunately, I often forget that I've stopped mailgun `process.env.MAIL_URL` while making changes to the app in the local devlopment environment, so when I push the update live I also stop emails from sending in the production environment. Is there a way to move the `process.env.MAIL_URL` to a settings-prod.js or something, so I stop making this mistake. I currently have a `settings-prod.js` and a `settings-dev.js` for public and private settings, but I think this is for keys.

**Curent method**
Path: `server/server.js`

```
Meteor.startup(function(options, user) {
  //load email server - to send email
  process.env.MAIL_URL = "mailgun en";
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact use case for environment settings, in particular what you should automatically have set to `process.env` instead of setting it yourself at `Meteor.startup`.

See:

- https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#environment
- https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/making-use-of-settings-json/

Typically you have 2 different setting files (1 for your dev, 1 for your prod), possibly with different Mailgun links, or you could more simply use a flag (e.g. `"sendEmails" = false` or read `"NODE_ENV"` property). Just be aware that some hosting services convert all values to `string` (hence `"sendEmails" = false` becomes `"sendEmails" = "false"` and is *truthy*...).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm trying to implement it now.